How can I unit test a Tauri app with a sqlite database?
I’m creating my first Tauri app based on Vite. It uses the plugin tauri-plugin-sql for a sqlite database.
I want to create now unit tests for my methods that interacts with a temporary test sqlite database.
It looks like that it is not possible with Vitest to access the Rust part of the app (only Mocking is possible).
Is there a workaround for it?
I was thinking about two dirty approaches:

To run the tests while the app is running with an app argument --test. But when I call the describe or test method, then Vitest is missing it context. Is there another framework that can do this? The prod app would not have this unit tests in it.

To use the NodeJS sqlite3 module for the unit tests, which works fine with Vitest. But I would need a TS interface that contains the tauri-plugin-sql-api methods and 2 wrapper classes that implements the interface (one for the tauri-plugin-sql-api and one for the sqlite3 module). The methods that I want to test will use then the interface. Exists there already such wrapper.


All other solutions are welcome.

For unit tests, mocking is the only option. These would be other kinds of tests otherwise

Hi Estus,
maybe it is a little bit more than a classical unit test. But I just want to write some small test methods for the app internal “DB API layer”. The test methods calls a DB API method to insert or update data in a temporary test database and calls another DB API method to select it again (completely without any business logic). The test is passed, if the source data and the selected data are equal.

But it's either unit test or not. It tests a single unit, the rest are supposed to be mocked. Did you check https://tauri.app/v1/guides/testing/mocking ? You can fully mock a plugin or create an adapter for node's in-memory sqlite lib, I doubt there's an existing one. It seems you tried this in (2) and it looks the right direction.

If you want an integration test, probably you'd need a separate build to avoid this problem, "prod app would not have this unit tests ". It's unclear what you did in (1) with --test arg, but vitest is supposed to run in node environment. And you'd need to communicate with Tauri's rust part from node. Probably can be done with Tauri remote IPC, but I honestly never investigated this option
